# I try to edit my web page using elementor and telling me this error and its on local host

Tags: wordpress, elementor, google-web-designer

cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: my.elementor.com

I try to edit with elementor and telling these errors above and also the web site is localhost.
I try to solve it and I deactivate all the plugins in order to find the culprit but its not working again;
also I deactivate all the themes still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same issue, I have tried several troubleshooting like, deactivating plugins, switching to the default theme, deleted .htaccess file, using litespeed cache plugin to purge cache yet none is fixing this issue
This issue started sometimes around the later days of December 2023.

Well, after several attempts to fix this issue failed, the only thing I notice is that, when I connect to the internet and try to open the pages in the localhost with Elementor, it opens straight away. Then I will disconnect the inetrnet and continue with the editing.